# MongoDB pushing to multiple subdocuments in same query

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection like this one.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d729d41b2f209e6f96034f0"),
    "selections" : [ 
        {
            "selectionId" : 1.0,
            "data" : [ 
                {
                    "value" : 1.0,
                    "index" : 1.0
                }, 
                {
                    "value" : 2.0,
                    "index" : 2.0
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "selectionId" : 2.0,
            "data" : [ 
                {
                    "value" : 1.0,
                    "index" : 1.0
                }, 
                {
                    "value" : 2.0,
                    "index" : 2.0
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And I can make two queries to update two subdocuments:

```
db.getCollection('test').update(
    { 
        "_id": ObjectId("5d729d41b2f209e6f96034f0"),
        "selections.selectionId" : 1,
    },
    { 
        "$push": {
            "selections.$.data" : {
                    value: 3,
                    index: 3
                }
        }
    }
)

db.getCollection('test').update(
    { 
        "_id": ObjectId("5d729d41b2f209e6f96034f0"),
        "selections.selectionId" : 2,
    },
    { 
        "$push": {
            "selections.$.data" : {
                    value: 3,
                    index: 3
                }
        }
    }
)
```

Is it possible to do it in one query?

Edit: I tried the following query also from first answer:

```
db.getCollection('test').update(
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("5d729d41b2f209e6f96034f0")
    }, 
    { 
        $push: { 
            "selections.$[s1].data": { value: 3, index: 3 }, 
            "selections.$[s2].data": { value: 4, index: 4 } 
        }
    },
    { 
        arrayFilters:
        [
            { "s1.selectionId": 1 },
            { "s2.selectionId": 2 }
        ]
    }
)
```

But it says:

```
> No array filter found for identifier 's1' in path
> 'selections.$[s1].data'
```

Comment: You want to add the same data to each subdocument?

Comment: No, different data, but this is an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `arrayFilters` and [positional filtered](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) operator:

```
db.col.update({ "_id": ObjectId("5d729d41b2f209e6f96034f0") }, 
    { $push: { 
        "selections.$[s1].data": { value: 3, index: 3 }, 
        "selections.$[s2].data": { value: 3, index: 3 } 
    } },
    { arrayFilters: [ { "s1.selectionId": 1 }, { "s2.selectionId": 2 } ] }
)
```

Comment: Simple and Precise :)

Comment: Tried it and it does not work, I edited the question with more details

Comment: @dfilkovi just read the message - if you know there's a document with `selectionId`: `1` then you use this filter, otherwise you remove it. I guess it might be a matter of BSON types so try `1.0` instead of `1`. I've tested that having `1` and it worked

Comment: But selections is array of subdocuments I need to push to a bunch of subdocuments indentified by selectionid, please look at the example of the document

Comment: @dfilkovi this is fine. You cannot use `$` positional opearator because it only supports single element so you need to use arrayFilters. I think the missing part was query so try to take a look at my edited answer

Comment: Does not work, it still says: No array filter found for identifier 's1' in path 'selections.$[s1].data'

Comment: What MongoDB version ?

Comment: It works from the shell, I did not work from RoboMongo, it seems like an old version :(